# Is editing website links into existing answers spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

I have an answer with a lot of votes on stackoverflow, that recently a user edited in a website link to an article written by an author of the same name.

Is this considered spam?

I'm tempted to edit the link to point to the relevant official documentation, as I don't see any reason for this person to be hijacking pageviews.

Comment: [This is the relevant revision](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16565640/2). Yea, that's not cool. I'd edit it if I were you.

Comment: I went ahead and rolled back about another dozen of their edits, and flagged them for moderator attention as well.  That's irritating.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Per [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion):

> ...you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.

[The edit in question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16565640/2) did not make it clear that the editor was also the author of the site to which they were linking, so **yes, this is considered spam**. Also:

> **Don't include links except to *support* what you've written.** Links are not a substitute for including information in your answer
>   itself...

Even if the affiliation had been disclosed, that wouldn't be an appropriate edit.

I would **roll the edit back**; you can add an alternative link if you think the answer needs it and you have an appropriate one, but it's not necessary.

---

It appears that the editor has a bit of form for hijacking others' answers with unattributed links to their own material (see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26554002/2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27178424/3)), so I would also strongly consider flagging for moderator attention, explaining the pattern.

Comment: Thanks! Edited out his link. Flagged it as well and pointed to this question thread with the examples of the user doing it in multiple places. Feels weird flagging my own answer however!

Comment: @Chris don't worry, the mods are generally disinclined to shoot the messenger!

Answer (score 14):

Yes, this is obviously spam. Furthermore, it's not even a good edit in its own right, with a *terrible* link caption and no punctuation for the added sentence, let alone any indication as to why one would want to "follow here". It's just completely pointless all around.

And from a 10k user, too! I'm disappointed.

Looking at his profile, this is not even the first time. There are *tens* of instances of it.
**I think it's time for moderators to have a little chat with this guy.**

*(A few folks have now rolled back most of the edits, but I've just rolled back a few they missed.)*

Comment: I think it's safe to assume we had a very pointed conversation with them at the time this Meta question was posted. Everyone agrees this was not acceptable behavior. Thought we'd gotten all the edits, thanks for finding the rest.

Comment: @Brad: np :) I think the main motivation for this answer was to put forth a slightly different context for the edits being rejectable (i.e. I don't mention attribution but quality, relevance and perceived intent). Also, although I realised later from reading more closely that this was not true, I thought I was discovering the user's edit history.